# how can I use facebook SDK in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook

I'm currently using react, and by using react-facebook-rogin Library, I successfully made facebook login. However, there is no function for logout!.

So I decided to use facebook SDK, however I don't know how to use javascript code in react.

according to facebook official document, I need to write following code in HTML.

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : 'your-app-id',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v11.0'
    });
  };
</script>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
```

And after, this is the code for log out

```
FB.logout(function(response) {
  // user is now logged out
});
```

And this is the code that I used react-facebook-rogin Library.

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import { BrowserRouter as Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import './components/Navbar.css';
import './App.css';
import MainStructure from "./pages/MainStructure";
import Study from "./pages/Study"
import FacebookLogin from 'react-facebook-login'
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  
  const responseFacebook = (response) => {
    console.log(response);
    setIsLoggedin(true)
  }

  const [isLoggedin, setIsLoggedin] = useState(false);

  return (

    isLoggedin ?
      (<div>

        <Route path='/' >
          <Navbar/>
        </Route>


        <Route exact path='/' >
          <MainStructure/>
        </Route>

        <Route path='/study'>
          <Study/>
        </Route>
      </div>) 
      :
      (
        <div className="">
          <div className="facebookLogin">
            <FacebookLogin
              appId="145617534309548"
              autoLoad={true}
              fields="name,email,picture"
              //onClick={componentClicked}
              callback={responseFacebook} />
          </div>
        </div>)


  );
}

export default App;
```

How can I use javascript code in react code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would not use a library that is 3 years old for this, but you could try using "window.FB.logout" or "FB.logout" on click. Either way, instead of that old dependency, you could just load the JS SDK on your own. Here is an example how that could work (untested):

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
    const [isLoggedin, setIsLoggedin] = useState(false);

    const onLoginClick = () => {
        window.FB.login(...);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        window.fbAsyncInit = () => {
            window.FB.init({
                appId            : 'your-app-id',
                autoLogAppEvents : true,
                xfbml            : true,
                version          : 'v11.0'
            });
        };
        (function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    }, []);

    return (
        <div><button onClick={onLoginClick}>Login with Facebook</button></div>
    );
};
```

This should be a component that is only loaded once - a root component that is always there, for example.

**In that case, you can use FB.logout() as well, of course.**

Comment: there is an err, because FB is not defined. FB supposed to defined in URL module, How can I get it?

Comment: are you sure the js sdk is loaded correctly, in useEffect?

Comment: because FB is not defined and failed to compile, I can't test whether it is working on browser. I thinks the importing difference between react and javascript makes this problem. usually in react, import module by writing import ~~ from "react".

Comment: no, it should definitely work, there is no need to "import". FB is not defined because the JS SDK is not loaded (yet). so when are you using FB, and which line of code produces the error? FB.init or FB.login? and did you check out the browser console for errors? also check out the network tab to see if the js sdk gets loaded. instead of FB.init, try windows.FB.init, for example.

Comment: got the problem.. first window.FB this way is correct. second, when I import useEffect, I wrote "import useEffect from "react" " . and I changed like this  "import {useEffect} from "react" "   I don't know how {} makes this difference.. anyway Thank you so much

Comment: you are welcome - but i highly suggest reading about how import works - {} can be used for named exports/imports, for example. if you omit the brackets, you only import the default export.